# JavaFX throwing null pointer exception when trying to setText() for label

Tags: javafx, nullpointerexception

I'm making an application that requires threading and a GUI interface so the user can know the status of each thread. The program first starts the GUI and then precedes to create threads for the task.

This is the program that is called to launch the GUI:

```
    public class startGUI extends Application {

        @Override
        public void start(Stage primaryStage) throws Exception{
            Parent root = FXMLLoader.load(getClass().getResource("MainWindow.fxml"));
            primaryStage.setTitle("whatever");
            primaryStage.setScene(new Scene(root, 600, 400));
            primaryStage.show();
        
        }
    
        public static void launchGUI() {
           launch();
        }  
   }
```

And here is a simplified version of the FXML file being called:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>

<?import javafx.scene.control.Label?>
<?import javafx.scene.layout.AnchorPane?>
<?import javafx.scene.text.Font?>

<AnchorPane prefHeight="400.0" prefWidth="600.0" xmlns="http://javafx.com/javafx/15.0.1" xmlns:fx="http://javafx.com/fxml/1" fx:controller="packagename.Controller">
      <Label fx:id="Display1" alignment="CENTER" layoutX="259.0" layoutY="109.0" prefHeight="18.0" prefWidth="291.0" style="-fx-border-color: #000000;" text="null" />
      <Label fx:id="Display2" alignment="CENTER" layoutX="259.0" layoutY="155.0" prefHeight="18.0" prefWidth="291.0" style="-fx-border-color: #000000;" text="null" />
      <Label fx:id="Display3" alignment="CENTER" layoutX="259.0" layoutY="201.0" prefHeight="18.0" prefWidth="291.0" style="-fx-border-color: #000000;" text="null" />
      <Label fx:id="Display4" alignment="CENTER" layoutX="259.0" layoutY="247.0" prefHeight="18.0" prefWidth="291.0" style="-fx-border-color: #000000;" text="null" />
      <Label fx:id="Display5" alignment="CENTER" layoutX="259.0" layoutY="294.0" prefHeight="18.0" prefWidth="291.0" style="-fx-border-color: #000000;" text="null" />
      <Label fx:id="Display6" alignment="CENTER" layoutX="259.0" layoutY="341.0" prefHeight="18.0" prefWidth="291.0" style="-fx-border-color: #000000;" text="null" />
   </children>
</AnchorPane>
```

Here is my Controller class for the GUI. The main purpose to to receive the status updates from each thread and then set the corresponding display to the message. Everything else on the GUI does not change.

```
public class Controller{
    @FXML public Label Display1, Display2, Display3, Display4, Display5, Display6;
    
    public void setThreadStatus(String threadName, String message) {
        switch(threadName) {
        case("thread 1"):
            Display1.setText(message);
        case("thread 2"):
            Display2.setText(message);
        case("thread 3"):
            Display3.setText(message);
        case("thread 4"):
            Display4.setText(message);
        case("thread 5"):
            Display5.setText(message);
        case("thread 6"):
            Display6.setText(message);
        }   
    }   
}
```

Finally, each thread will run the program below and call the .setThreadStatus() from the Controller to update the GUI.

```
    public class runTask(){    
        public static runSequence(threadName){
            public static Controller controller = new Controller();
            **runs the program and periodically gives updates by using the code below***
            controller.setThreadStatus(threadName, update_message);
        }
    }
```

Everything works perfectly except for the fact that everytime a thread calls .setThreadStatus() there is a null pointer exception. Can anyone help?

Comment: `@FXML`-annotated fields will only be set in the actual controller. They won't be set in arbitrary objects of the same type. (If you loaded the FXML twice, for example, so you had two labels called `display1`, two called `display2`, etc., which ones would be injected into your new controller instance?)

Comment: Kind of OT, but: Also note that you can't change the text of a label from a thread other than the FX application thread. After fixing the issue with the wrong instance of the controller class, you'll need to thread this properly according to JavaFX threading rules.

Comment: java naming conventions please

Comment: @James_D do you think using a singleton class would fix the issue?

Comment: Huh? No. How would that even work?